# why getid from firabase authentication got error?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Currently I insert name, email, password and age successfully to the firebase database but until I tried to insert the value from selected radiobutton then the nightmare came to me. The problem is the data sometimes can insert to database but now even the authentication part also cannot insert So I wondering how can I solve this problem?

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth auth;
private EditText run, rpw,re;
private EditText rpn, ra, rpc;
private TextView rage;
private String usnm, pswd, email, age, uid;
private FirebaseDatabase db;
private DatabaseReference ref;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dsl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = db.getReference();
    FirebaseUser ur = auth.getCurrentUser();
    uid = ur.getUid();//getuser id

    run = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Run);
    rpw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpw);
    rage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Rage);

    rage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Calendar mc = Calendar.getInstance();
            int y = mc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int m = mc.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = mc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(Register.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth, dsl, y, m, day);

            dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mc.getTimeInMillis());
            dpd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dpd.show();
        }
    });

    dsl = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            month = month+1;

            String date = dayOfMonth +"/" + month + "/" +year;
            rage.setText(date);
        }
    };

    re = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Re);
    rpn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpn);
    ra = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ra);
    rpc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Rpc);

    //rbstd = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbstd);
    //rbtt= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbtt);

    final Button br = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Rbt);

    br.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            usnm = run.getText().toString().trim();
            pswd = rpw.getText().toString().trim();
            email = re.getText().toString().trim();
            age = rage.getText().toString().trim();

            validateUsername(usnm);

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pswd)){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password cannot be empty", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (pswd.length()<8){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password cannot less then 8 characters", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (pswd.length()>12){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password cannot greater then 12 characters", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(age)){
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Please select date", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }

            validateEmail(email);

            register(usnm, pswd, age, email);

        }//end of onclick
    });


}

private void register (final String un, final String pw, final String ag, final String em){
    Task<AuthResult> authResultTask = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(em, pw).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                //insertion
                User u = new User (un, pw, ag, em);
                ref.child(uid).setValue(u);

                //prompt message
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Success Registration", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, StudentHomePage.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });


}// end of signup

private void validateUsername(final String validateName){

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(validateName)){
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username cannot be empty", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

    }else if (validateName.length()<8){
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username cannot less then 8 characters", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

    }else if (validateName.length()>12){
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username cannot greater then 12 characters", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

    }else {


            ref.child(uid).orderByChild("username").equalTo(validateName).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot!=null && dataSnapshot.getChildren()!=null && dataSnapshot.hasChild(validateName)){

                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username had been taken", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;

                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username unique", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Database Connection Error", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            });


    }
}

private void validateEmail(final String valiemail){
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(valiemail)){
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username cannot be empty", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

    }else {

        ref.child(uid).orderByChild("email").equalTo(valiemail).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot!=null && dataSnapshot.getChildren()!=null && dataSnapshot.hasChild(valiemail)){

                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Email had been taken", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;

                }else{

                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Email unique", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Database Connection Error", 
LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return;
            }
        });

    }
}

}
```

The logcat shows

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString'

Please advice me to solve this problem.
The application stopped working when I want to insert and now the whole register page cannot show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the user and their `uid` in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = db.getReference();
    FirebaseUser ur = auth.getCurrentUser();
    uid = ur.getUid();//getuser id
```

There is no guarantee that there is an authenticated user when the activity gets created. This is why you can attach a listener for when the authentication state changes. By listening for that, you can react to when the user is signed in or out.

```
auth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Register.this.uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        }
        else {
            Register.this.uid = null;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: but where should I insert the listener ?

Comment: In the `onCreate` of your activity is fine for that.

Comment: Not working got message like 09-03 13:19:18.136 17404-17422/com.example.rex.ota30 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

Comment: That's a different problem. https://www.google.com/search?q=DynamiteModule%3A+Local+module+descriptor+class+for+com.google.firebase.auth+not+found

Comment: I found out my problem already. I missed the line of <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 0):

since i don't have enough reputation to comment what I advice for this is that

- before getting uId you should check **if(ur!=null)**, if its null it needs more debugging ( making sure user has logged in)
- secondly update firebase libraries to latest version I am not sure which version but I have encountered getCurentUser() returning null unless you sign out and login twice. But thankfully its currently fixed.
  I hope this helps someone !

Comment: if (ur!=null) also not working...last time i didnt get value from radio button and the insertion still work but after 3 days of getting value from radiobutton then it suddenly appear the message of apps stopped working. So regret to use the radio button><

Comment: when i done entering the value then click the button then it show the apps stopped working. Very frustrated about it.